# $\forall n \in Z$ prove that if $\exists a,b \in Z$ s.t. $a^2+b^2=n$ then $n \not\equiv 3\pmod{4}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$\forall n \in Z$ prove that if $\exists a,b \in Z$ s.t. $a^2+b^2=n$ then $n \not\equiv 3\pmod{4}$

Just checking my work. I decided to prove the contrapositive of the implication instead, which is(and I hope this is correct).
$\forall n \in Z$ If $n \equiv 3\pmod{4}$ then $\forall a,b \in Z$ s.t. $a^2+b^2\ne n$

So if $n\bmod4=3\bmod4$ then $n=4k+3=2(k+1)+1, k\in I$. So we can see it must be an odd then if we choose $a$ and $b$ to have the same parity then their sums will be even, because and even plus an even is an even and an odd plus an odd is an odd.

If they are opposite parity though then WLOG $a=2k, k\in I$ and $b=2j+1 j\in I$. Then $a^2+b^2=2(2j^2+2i^2+2ij)+1$, which is odd but we can see that $(2j^2+2i^2+2ij)$ is even where as $n$ is 2 times an odd plus 1. So they will never be equal because $2(2k+1)+1 \ne 2(2j)+1, k,j\in I$

Is this right?

Comment: Does "$n(mod4) \ne 3(mod4)$" mean $n\not\equiv3\pmod 4$?

Comment: the notation $n(mod4) \ne 3(mod4)$ is not common, generally it is written as $n\not\equiv 3\mod 4$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$a^2\equiv 1$ or $ 0\pmod 4$

$b^2\equiv 1$ or $0\pmod4$.

Therefore , $a^2 +b^2\equiv 0$ or $1$ or $2 \pmod4$.